# Cannot protect user form accesing sign-in page with guard in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase-authentication, auth-guard

I would like to prevent user from accessing login page if already logged. I'm using Angular with Firebase authentication.

I successfully prevent user from accessing the app by writing an **auth.guard.ts** like that :

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRouteSnapshot, CanActivate, Router, RouterStateSnapshot, UrlTree } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map, tap} from 'rxjs/operators';
import { AuthentificationService } from '../services/authentification.service';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  
  constructor(
    private authService: AuthentificationService,
    private router: Router
  ) {

  }

  canActivate(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree> | boolean | UrlTree {
    return this.authService.user$
      .pipe(map(authState => !!authState))
      .pipe(tap(auth => !auth ? this.router.navigate(['sign-in']) : true))
  }
}
```

and then inject it in my **app.routing.ts** and it works perfectly :

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  { 
    path: '', 
    redirectTo: '/sign-in',
    pathMatch: 'full',
  },
  { 
    path: 'sign-in', 
    component: SignInComponent,
    //canActivate: [AnonymousGuard]
  },
  { 
    path: 'scanner', 
    component: ScannerComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
  },
  { 
    path: 'view-entries', 
    component: ViewEntriesComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
  },
  { 
    path: '**', 
    redirectTo: ''
  }

];
```

Then, I just told myself that to protect the login page, I just have to write an **anonymous.guard.ts** in almost the same way and inject it as above.

```js
export class AnonymousGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(    
    private authService: AuthentificationService,
    private router: Router) { }

  canActivate(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree> | boolean | UrlTree {
    return this.authService.user$
      .pipe(map(authState => !!authState))
      .pipe(tap(auth => !!auth))
      .pipe(tap(auth => auth ? this.router.navigate(['scanner']) : true))
  }
  
}
```

But by doing so, my application is stuck when I sign out/when I'm not logging. And I do not understand why...
What I'm doing wrong ?

[EDIT] My service is just keeping the observable to make it accessible in the app like this :

```js
  user$: Observable<any>;

  constructor(
    private angularFireAuth: AngularFireAuth,
    private router: Router
  ) {
    this.user$ = this.angularFireAuth.authState;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can apply ‘ Route Guards’ to an authenticated area of your web app, or an admin section that requires special permissions to be accessed.

Comment: Are we able to get specific examples of what a route guard is or how you'd implement an "Admin section"

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Can you provide an example please ? I already implemented Route Guards as you can see with my auth.gaurd.ts. And I do not want an admin section. I just want to prevent the user to sign in several times in one session.